# order columns by display order and parent id

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a dataset where I have a list of rows, each with an `ID`, display `order` and a nullable `parentID`. I need them to be returned in ascending display order grouped behind their parent if they have one. I'm not sure how to go about this. I was thinking about trying some unions but there would be an unbound number of them needed.

```
ID  order   parentID
4   1   
6   2   
5   1       6
1   2       6
7   3       6
77  3   
89  1       77
43  4   
23  5   
2   1       23
3   2       23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct an ordering mechanism that accounts for ordering between levels as well as ordering within each level. I'll show you how to do it using a recursive CTE.

First, you need to determine how many elements you could be comparing. In your table, the answer is up to 5, but this could be arbitrary. So we'll query for that first

```
declare @dyn_ord as int = (select len(MAX(ordering)) from #A)
```

This gets the number of digits, which in this case is just 1. Here, I'm using '#A' as the name of your table.

Next, we set up the recursive CTE with the fields we want

```
declare @dyn_ord as int = (select len(MAX(ordering)) from #A)

; with
    Parent as (
    -- Anchor member definition
        select    a.Id -- of course show the ID
                , a.parentID -- show the parent's ID
                , cast(a.ID as varchar(max)) as Path -- this is bonus to help understand recursion
                , CAST((REPLACE(STR(ordering,@dyn_ord),' ','0')) AS nvarchar(max)) AS OrderString -- our modified ordering, explanation to follow
            from #A a
            where a.parentId is null
        union all
    -- Recursive member definition
        select    c.Id
                , c.parentID
                , cast(Path + ' -> ' + cast(c.ID as varchar(max)) as varchar(max)) as Path
                , (p.OrderString + '.' + CAST((REPLACE(STR(c.ordering,@dyn_ord),' ','0')) AS nvarchar(max))) AS OrderString
            from #A as c
            inner join Parent as p
                on c.parentID = p.ID
    )
SELECT    Id
        , parentID
        , Path
        , OrderString
    FROM Parent
    order by OrderString asc
```

OrderString is the mechanism that we use to order. In a given level, it (1) takes the ordering, (2) casts it as a string, and (3) pads any extra zeros as needed. The third step is needed in case you were trying to compare orderings like 1 and 10, which doesn't always give you what you want in string comparisons.

In the recursion step, 'OrderString' (1) takes the ordering that's already there from the parent, (2) appends a period (not needed but helpful for understanding the ordering), and (3) then does the same three steps as in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Holy crap. There is a lot for me to learn from this, thank you very very much!

Comment: You're welcome :) Play around with this for a little bit to get a better feel of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Just put all the columns you want to sort by in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select parentID, ordering, ID
from mytab
order by parentID, ordering
```

(I've renamed `order` to ordering, since `order` is a SQL keyword)

**UPDATE**

To move the NULL parentIDs to the bottom, you can use `NULLS LAST` if your RDBMS supports it:

```
select parentID, ordering, ID
from mytab
order by parentID nulls last, ordering
```

Comment: doing it that way just puts all the rows with null parent at the top, and all of them with a non-null parent at the bottom

Comment: @DanWier In your question, you haven't mentioned where you want the NULL values. Anyway, see my updated answer for an approach that might work (if that doesn't work, you should edit your question and tag it with the appropriate RDBMS to get more specific answers).